# Enable,Disable button upon check/uncheck of checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a view that contains a list box with various items in button form and a checkbox for each of the button. XAML:

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckFavorite"
                              Width="Auto"
                              Height="Auto"
                              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_FavoritesCheck"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked,
                                                  Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Visibility="{Binding IsFavoriteConfiguredAndInDA,
                                                   Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"
                              Checked="OnContentChanged"
                              Unchecked="OnContentChanged"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1"
                            Width="240"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AID_BtnLaunchFavorite"
                            Command="{Binding Path=LaunchFavorite}"
                            Content="{Binding Path=ModuleDisplayName}"
                            Cursor="Hand"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource UxLevel_5}"
                            Padding="24 12 2 12"
                            ToolTip="{Binding Path=ModuleDisplayName}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I have another button called "Launch". Its basic functionality is to launch the tasks as per the selection in the above listbox items so that multiple tasks can be launched.Button XAML:

```
        <Button Name="btnLaunch"
                Width="80"
                Height="25"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AUI_BtnLaunchForFavorite"
                Command="{Binding LaunchCommand}"
                Style="{StaticResource LaunchButtonStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding IsRIAMode,
                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityInverter}}">
```

Issue:
I want to enable/disable this launch button if atleast one item is selected and disable otherwise.How can i achieve? Pls help with some code snippets.

UPDATE:
Here is the launch command:

```
public ICommand LaunchCommand { get; private set; }
LaunchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLaunch);
        internal void OnLaunch(object sender)
        {
            var nFavItemToLaunchCount = Favorites.Count(favItem => favItem.IsChecked);

            if (!IsSessionLimitReached(nFavItemToLaunchCount))
            {
                foreach (FavoriteItemViewModel favoriteItem in Favorites)
                {
                    if (favoriteItem.IsChecked)
                    {
                        favoriteItem.LaunchFavorite.Execute(sender);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE 2:

I made the changes as per Krishna's comment:

```
 LaunchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLaunch,ToggleLaunch);
 private bool ToggleLaunch(object obj)
 {

      if (Favorites.Count(i => i.IsChecked)!=0)  //Favorites is the itemsource
      {
                return true;
      }
            return false;
 }
```

Still the launch button is shown disabled always even when item is selected/checked.

UPDATE 3

After Krishna's further comment, i changed the implementation of the property IsChecked and also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the viewmodel.Still no luck!

```
public class FavoriteItemViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return m_IsChecked;
            }
            set
            {
                m_IsChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handler for property change
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of property</param>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

There is another viewmodel "FavoriteContainerViewModel" that holds the collection of "FavoriteItemViewModel"  and also implements INotifyPropertyChanged. This container view model is the place where i added the code mentioned in UPDATE 2

UPDATE 4:
Implementation of favorites:

```
public class FavoriteContainerViewModel : ViewModelBase, IModuleView
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<FavoriteItemViewModel> m_Favorites = new ObservableCollection<FavoriteItemViewModel>();

        public ObservableCollection<FavoriteItemViewModel> Favorites
        {
            get { return m_Favorites; }
        }
        public FavoriteContainerViewModel()
        {
            LaunchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLaunch, ToggleLaunch);
            OnLoad();
        }
        private bool ToggleLaunch(object obj)
        {
            if (Favorites.Count(i => i.IsChecked) != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
            //return true;
        }
}
```

Note:ViewModelBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Update 5:
Problem now resolved using event based model. Implemented following:
FavoriteViewModel.cs

```
public event EventHandler ItemChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get
    {
        return m_IsChecked;
    }
    set
    {
        m_IsChecked = value;
        if (ItemChecked != null)
        {
            ItemChecked(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

FavoriteItemContainerViewModel.cs

```
private void SubscribeFavoriteItemEvents(FavoriteItemViewModel favorite)
{
     favorite.ItemChecked += ToggleLaunchButton;
}

private bool m_IsLaunchEnabled;
public bool IsLaunchEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return m_IsLaunchEnabled;
    }
    set
    {
        m_IsLaunchEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsLaunchEnabled");
    }
}
```

Property IsLaunchEnabled is binded to the button to enable/disable.

Comment: What is `LaunchCommand`?

Comment: LaunchCommand is executed when this button is clicked and launches the selected tasks.

Comment: Yes, but what class is it instance of? Your own `ICommand`  implementation or some toolkit class? Do you have `CanExecute` method? If so, enable/disable the button in that method.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable/disable the `Button` based on the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property:

```
<Button Name="btnLaunch"
                Width="80"
                Height="25"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AUI_BtnLaunchForFavorite"
                Command="{Binding LaunchCommand}"
                Style="{StaticResource LaunchButtonStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding IsRIAMode,
                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityInverter}}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=CheckFavorite, Path=IsChecked}">
```

Comment: Are the `Button` and the `Checkbox` in the same Visual Tree?

Comment: No, checkbox is part of the list box whereas button is in altogether different stackpanel

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the launch button is outside the listbox and user clicks it once the checkboxes are checked.

In that case, you need to add a condition in the 'CanExecute' part of your ICommand (LaunchCommand)

Lets assume your ICommand implementation in the constructor is something like

```
LaunchCommand = new RelayCommand(launchMethod);
private void launchMethod(object obj)
{
//do some work here
}
```

Now add canExecute part to your command by changing the initialisation

```
LaunchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLaunch,checkCheckboxes);
```

and add this method

```
private bool checkCheckboxes(object obj)
{
   //YourList is your itemsource
   return YourList.Where(i=>i.IsChecked).Any();
}
```

Just change the above method to suit your needs

Update change your IsChecked property to below

```
private bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Then change your implementation like LaunchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLaunch,checkCheckboxes); and add my method mentioned in my post for checkCheckboxes. You just need to make sure atleast one item is checked and if it is, then return true and if no item is checked then return false. That will enable and disable your launch button automatically

Comment: Can you please help me out with the code snippet to check for atleast one selected item?I am new to WPF

Comment: I added this code:            if (Favorites.Count(i => i.IsChecked)!=0)
            {
                return true;
            }, still the button is shown disabled even when one of the item checked.

Comment: That is exactly what my code is doing. Change your LaunchCommand implementation (that single line) replace with my implementation and add the checkCheckboxes method and it should work for you.

Comment: Did you add onPropertyChanged to your IsChecked property? Can you post the implementation of your IsChecked property from your ViewModel?

Comment: public class FavoriteItemViewModel
    {public bool IsChecked { get; set; }}

Comment: See my update, change the IsChecked property. Change the onPropertyChanged line to suit your implementation (dont know how you are implementing propertychanged

Comment: I think you need to go back to the drawing board. Learn how binding works in WPF and how the NotifyPropertyChanged works as well. For a starter put some breakpoints and see whats going around. First of all in ToggleLaunch method, remove all the code and just return true; and see if the button is enabled always. If it is then atleast you are in the right track then you can start adding different conditions. If the button is disabled then check the style for the button and see if anything else is disabling it in the xaml. But first of all try the ToggleLaunch method by returning true always.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in togglelaunch method.Observations: 
1. Only the first time(at application load) this method got hit when IsChecked is false(obviously) so it returned false.
2.In UI when i checked the checkbox this method never got hit.

This is the real problem.Is the method supposed to get called each time the checkboxes are checked/unchecked?

Comment: Ok one last thing, post the implementation of Favorites.

Comment: Please see update 4.Also note that simply returning true from ToggleLaunch method results into the button enabled always

Comment: try changing your command from DelegateCommand to RelayCommand. Dont know what is going wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checkbox1.Checked && !checkbox2.Checked)
    {
      button1.Enable = true
    }
    else if (!checkbox1.Checked && checkbox2.Checked)
    {
      button1.Enable = false
    }
```